# How to group mongo doc based on key inside an array?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I've a collection that have this documents:

```
{
    sku: 1,
    values: [{x: false, z: 100}]
}
{
    sku: 1,
    values: [{z: 100}]
}
{
    sku: 2
    values: [{x: false, z: 100}]
}
```

> Note that the document with `sku` `2` is not duplicated but it have the key `x` in a object inside an array.

How do i query the documents grouping by `sku` and get the one that does not have the key `x` but at the same time also get the `sku` that is not duplicated but have the `x` key?

The result that i expect is:

```
{
    sku: 1,
    values: [{z: 100}]
}
{
    sku: 2,
    values: [{x: false, x: 100}]
}
```

I want to ignore a document if it is duplicated by the key `sku` and have the key`x: false` but if the document is not duplicated by `sku` to get it anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So rephrasing your requirements: you want to filter out all values with `x: false` if there's more than one document with particular `sku`

You need Aggregation Framework's [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) to get all the data for single `sku`. Then you can run [$reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/index.html) with [$concatArrays](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concatArrays/index.html) to flatten `values` array and [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/index.html) as a last step to apply your business rule:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$sku",
            count: { $sum: 1 },
            values: { $push: "$values" }
        }
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
            values: {
                $reduce: {
                    input: "$values",
                    initialValue: [],
                    in: { $concatArrays: [ "$$value", "$$this" ] }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            sku: "$_id",
            values: {
                $filter: {
                    input: "$values",
                    cond: {
                        $or: [
                            { $eq: [ "$count", 1 ] },
                            { $ne: [ "$$this.x", false ] }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/CgBz6ax9gSh)

Comment: how can i change this query to considere only the ones that doesn't have "x"? the logic is the same, "group" docs with same `sku` but get the doc that doesn't have the "x", i've tried change the `cond` on your query but it didn't work `"$$this.x": {$exists: false}`

Comment: @RafaAcioly you can try `$ne: [ "$$this.x", undefined ]`

Comment: i cannot use `undefined` because i'm using python to build the query, the closest that i have is `None` but it's converted to `null`, i've also tried `{$type: 6}`